# why was this foreign language post deleted just now?

Tags: discussion, english

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643298/c%EC%97%90%EC%84%9C-%ED%94%BD%EC%85%80%EC%9E%91%EC%97%85%EC%9D%84-%ED%95%A0-%EB%95%8C-%EC%9D%B4%EB%AF%B8%EC%A7%80%EC%97%90-%EB%94%B0%EB%9D%BC-rgb%EC%9D%B8%EC%A7%80-bgr%EC%9D%B8%EC%A7%80%EB%A5%BC-%EA%B5%AC%EB%B6%84%ED%95%98%EB%8A%94-%EB%B0%A9%EB%B2%95%EC%9D%84-%EC%95%8C%EB%A0%A4%EC%A3%BC%EC%84%B8%EC%9A%94) just now and wanted to comment on it but it was deleted.

is stack English only or are there foreign stack sites that non-English speaking folks should be using?

I do see people that struggle with English getting down votes for poor questions when really there is just a language barrier.

[image]

Comment: @George Stocker what about the second question of foreign stack sites? are there different versions of the site? and I wasn't asking how to deal with. just wondering why. which the question that you referenced answered. THANKS

Comment: Stack Overflow is English only. Stack Exchange isn't. One example: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ And you can find plenty of "SO in X" examples on http://area51.stackexchange.com/